# How to make EXPECT condition to wait for promise to be resolved (code wrapped in a method)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

When I tried using following piece of code within the test body, it seems to work fine except the fact that code after (outside) this block is still getting executed and and test fails at the end.

```
var el = element(by.model('name.first'));
    el.isDisplayed().then(function(condition) {
        console.log("Is Element Displayed : " + condition);
        if(!condition) {
            fail('Test Failed');
        }
    });
```

But when I wrap this code inside a method (in some other util file) like:

```
isMyElementDisplayed: function (element) {
    var el = element;
    el.isDisplayed().then(function(condition) {
        console.log("Is Element Displayed : " + condition);
        return condition;
    });
}
```

and then try to call this method in my test like:

```
expect(elementActions.isMyElementDisplayed(element(by.model('name.first')))).toBe(true);
```

it fails with following exception.

`Expected undefined to be true.`

however I see the message getting printed in the logs:
`Is Element Displayed : false`

and still, in this case as well, the test doesn't stop at the 'expect' condition but fails at the end. You can tell I am new to protractor and javascript. I am trying to automate QA functional tests and build some reusable methods that can be used again and by others too.

1. Is there a correct way to wrap the code within a util method like I am doing? and
2. How to make `expect` condition to wait till the promise is resolved?

FYI: npm -version -> 2.14.7 and protractor --version -> 3.0.0

Comment: You need to return the promise from the `isMyElementDisplayed` first

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev can you please guide how to do that in this case. That would be really helpful. You can also post that as answer, I will accept if that solved my problem.

Comment: I was not sure, that this is the only problem, so I could not post it as an answer, but there is one now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Artyom pointed out was to put `return` into the `isMyElementDisplayed` function:

```
isMyElementDisplayed: function (element) {
    var el = element;

    // v HERE
    return el.isDisplayed().then(function(condition) {
        console.log("Is Element Displayed : " + condition);
        return condition;
    });
}
```

This way the `isMyElementDisplayed` function would return a promise which would be put on the control flow and `expect` would resolve it implicitly before making an assertion.

---

Though, I would use a *wait* to handle the problem:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var elm = element(by.model('name.first'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm), 5000, "Element is still not visible");

expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```